# When I try to open this activity I'm getting nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is my main class file of activity:

```
public class product extends AppCompatActivity {

    String name[] = {
            "q",
            "w",
            "e",
            "r",
            "t",
            "y",
            "u"
    };

    Integer pisc[] = {
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.e,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e,
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.d
    };
    String location[] = {
            "a",
            "s",
            "dr",
            "d",
            "f",
            "r",
            "r"
    };

    String lang[] = {
            "Hindi",
            "Hindi",
            "Hindi",
            "Hindi",
            "Hindi",
            "Hindi",
            "Hindi"

    };

    Float rating[] = {
            5f,
            4.5f,
            4.5f,
            4f,
            4f,
            3.5f,
            3f

    };

    String rate[] = {
            "Rated by 452+ people",
            "Rated by 427+ people",
            "Rated by 369+ people",
            "Rated by 332+ people",
            "Rated by 279+ people",
            "Rated by 259+ people",
            "Rated by 129+ people"
    };


    TextView naam,loc,langs,rat;
    Button thumbnails;
    ListView hind;
    RatingBar rates;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);


        hind = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hindpro);
        naam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameh);
        loc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locations);
        langs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lang);
        rat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
        thumbnails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pic);
        rates = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);



        class customadapterpz extends BaseAdapter {



            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return name.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int positionq, View convertView, ViewGroup 
         parent) {
                View view4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hindpro, 
null);


                if (name[positionq] != null) {




                    Bitmap bitmahind = 
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(product.this.getResources(),
                            pisc[positionq], 150, 150);
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawableaw = new 
BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmahind);
                    thumbnails.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawableaw);
                   // thumbnails.setImageBitmap(bitmahind);
                    naam.setText(name[positionq]);
                    loc.setText(location[positionq]);
                    langs.setText(lang[positionq]);
                    rat.setText(rate[positionq]);
                    rates.setRating(rating[positionq]);

                }

                return view4;
            }
        }

        customadapterpz item23 = new customadapterpz();
        hind.setAdapter(item23);






    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int 
resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, 
reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, 
int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 4;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 8;
            final int halfWidth = width / 8;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 
and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 8;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

This xml of activty:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sometextview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hindpro"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2">
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This custom xml file for listview:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locations"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameh"

        android:layout_below="@+id/nameh"
        android:text="Mansarovar, jaipur" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Hindi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/locations"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/locations" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/locations" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rated by 129 people"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/book"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lang" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/book"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOOK"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to open this activity from another activity I'm getting **null pointer exception**

I tried everything I know including double checking every single line of code and renaming every tag so that they doesn't match with any other tag.
So please guys, take a look at the code and tell me what's wrong.

logcat:

```
05-27 21:56:19.974 22216-22216/com.example.pankaz.qw E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.pankaz.qw, PID: 22216
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.pankaz.qw.product$1customadapterpz.getView(product.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: updated .. check log and tell me please

Comment: some pics are missing from your drawable check all drawable's

Comment: what is line no 137 in `product.java`?

Comment: it's java class name ....

Comment: nothing is missing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you initialized **thumbnails** in onCreate(). You should initialize it inside the adapter. Pass a **LayoutInflater** into the adapter. Then initialize thumbnails using the LayoutInflater inside the adapter.

Comment: Thanx Anees ... you just saved my life man ... Happy Ramadan man :)

Comment: Thanks bro same to you.